# issue with JS if condition alert

Tags: javascript

I'm newbie in javascript and trying to run the js file. my question is i'm trying to hold the randomItem() return value in var "luckyplace" and checking the if-else condition. when i run the file, its not giving me any alert for any of the condition and I don't see any error too. Please help !

```js
/*jslint devel: true */
alert("You are away from home long time, and you forgot where you kept the key. You have to search few places to find the key and get in !");

var places = ["flower pot", "under mat", "side of window", "top of front door"];
alert("place you can search are listed below:" + " " + places);

function randomItem(range) {
    "use strict";
    return Math.round(Math.random() * range);
}
alert(places[randomItem(places.length - 1)]);

var luckyplace = randomItem();

if (luckyplace === "flower pot") {
    alert("No key, no flowers !");
} else if (randomItem() === "under mat") {
    alert("Try somewhere else.");
} else if (randomItem() === "side of window") {
    alert("you are not lucky enough");
} else if (randomItem() === "top of front door") {
    alert("great ! you found the key. Unlock the door.");
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your random item function returns a random index, not an item in the array

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `randomItem` several times, and all but the first time you're forgetting to pass in the length and then look up the item in the `places` array. See my edit below; I'm not 100% sure that does what you want, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

```js
/*jslint devel: true */
alert("You are away from home long time, and you forgot where you kept the key. You have to search few places to find the key and get in !");

var places = ["flower pot", "under mat", "side of window", "top of front door"];
alert("place you can search are listed below:" + " " + places);

function randomItem(range) {
    "use strict";
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
}
var luckyplace = places[randomItem(places.length)];

alert(luckyplace);

if (luckyplace === "flower pot") {
    alert("No key, no flowers !");
} else if (luckyplace === "under mat") {
    alert("Try somewhere else.");
} else if (luckyplace === "side of window") {
    alert("you are not lucky enough");
} else if (luckyplace === "top of front door") {
    alert("great ! you found the key. Unlock the door.");
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using switch instead of `if...elseif` ladder. Also using `Math.floor` would make sure index is never going out of bounds.

Comment: If you decide to use `Math.floor`, pass `places.length` instead of `places.length - 1`. (I agree that this is better.)

Comment: I've updated my version of the code here to use the `Math.floor` method, since I have more confidence that this yields a truly random result. (I'm worried that depending on the rounding algorithm, the results may not be truly random in the original code.)

Comment: @Rajesh, Thanks for the suggesting Math.floor and it makes lot of sense.

Comment: @smarx, yes using Math.floor makes it much more better. Thanks for the insights.